# UL CSS issue with border

Tags: css, border, html-lists

I am desperately trying to find a way to get this working. I have a menu that use images for links. But in IE and FF there is an annoying border around the image that I don't know how to get rid of.

Would you be able to quickly tell me the CSS attribute to avoid this effect.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Antonio

Comment: Install Firebug in FF, and change its css as suggestion below, I think will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li img { border: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about the implicit `outline` or `border` that are added to `img` elements within `a` tags.

The fix is simple:

```
a img
{
  border: 0 none;
  outline: 0 none;
}
```

The `outline` may no longer be necessary, I'm not sure if any browsers use `outline` for the effect any more.

Edit to add:

For some reason in FF/IE, the specificity of `img` or `a` is too low to override the default behavior.